# Regex detect if key is not inside quote

Tags: javascript, regex, prototypejs

I am totally new to regex and I just can't get it to work.
I have this Javascript code

```
html.replace(new RegExp(util.escapeRegex(key), 'g'), 'something');
```

But I would only like it to fire if `util.escapeRegex(key)` is outside from quotes `"/'`

Note that `key` is something like `:key:`

Comment: Add some example of the content you are matching. It should cointain some examples of the problems you want to solve. And is there some kind of escapes in the quotes that you want to avoid?

Comment: Yea show some input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no double quote is unbalanced, this should do the trick for you.

```
html.replace(new RegExp(util.escapeRegex(key) + '(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)', 'g'), 'something');
```

Comment: If you want to ignore single quotes as well, `(?=(?:(?:[^"\']*["\']){2})*[^"\']*$)`